# Fread returns zero for the while loop

Tags: c, cs50

I have a problem with pset4 recover in cs50, I'm trying to read 512 bytes into a buffer from a file but when the program operates nothing seems to happen. I have tried debug50 and it looks like there's a problem with the while loop

```
while(fread(buffer,sizeof (BYTE),512,f))
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 FILE *f=fopen(argv[1],"r");
 FILE *img= NULL;
 int count=0;
 char* filename= NULL;
 BYTE buffer[512];
 
 while(fread(buffer,sizeof (BYTE),512,f))
 {
     if(buffer[0]==0xff && buffer[1]==0xd8 && buffer[2]==0xff && ((buffer[3]&0xf0)==0xe0) )
     {
         if(img==NULL)
         {
             sprintf(filename,"%03i.jpg",count);
             count++;
             img=fopen(filename,"w");
             fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, img);
         }
        else
        {
             fclose(img);
             sprintf(filename,"%03i.jpg",count);
             count++;
             img=fopen(filename,"w");
             fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, img);
        }
     }
    if(img!=NULL)
     {
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 512, img);
     }
 }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `sprintf(filename,"%03i.jpg",count);` Where is the memory for your filename?

Comment: You never check return values for your function calls. That's a NO GO. I would suspect `fopen(NULL,"w")` does not return a useful pointer.

Comment: In case you find a header, you write your buffer twice.

Comment: In general, plrease try to provide useful information for us. What does "there is a problem with while loop" mean? That can be everything or nothing. Does it loop too often, only once, not often enough, not at all? Do you reach the loop at all? Provide specific and detailled information about what does or does not happen.

Comment: OT: regarding; `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 FILE *f=fopen(argv[1],"r");`  Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected command line parameter.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: for a robust program, always check the returned value from functions like: `fopen()`, `fread()`, fwrite()`

Comment: regarding: `}
    if(img!=NULL)`  there should be an 'else' before this `if()`  to avoid outputting the same line twice into the  current output file

Comment: regarding; `sprintf(filename,"%03i.jpg",count);`  The pointer: `filename` does not point to memory owned by the program.  The result is undefined behavior.  Suggest changing: `char* filename= NULL;` to `char filename[20];`

Comment: SO can only work if you provide feedback to questions and hints from comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    if (argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *f=fopen(argv[1],"r");
 
     if(f == NULL)
     {
          printf("Couldn't open\n");
           return 1;
     }
 
     FILE *img= NULL;
     int count=0;
     char filename[1000];
     BYTE buffer[512];
 
     while(fread(buffer,sizeof (buffer),1,f))
     {
          if(buffer[0]==0xff && buffer[1]==0xd8 && buffer[2]==0xff && ((buffer[3]&0xf0)==0xe0) )
          {
      
             if(img!=NULL)
                    fclose(img);
        
             sprintf(filename,"%03i.jpg",count);
             count++;
             img=fopen(filename,"a");
             if (img == NULL) 
              {
                   printf("Could not create file %03i/n", count );
                   return 1;
              }
     }
      
    if(img!=NULL)
             fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, img);
    
 }
     if(img!=NULL)
     {
        fclose(img);
     }
     fclose(f);
     return 0;
}
```